# anti-derivatives & applications of the fundamental theorem

Tags: integration

Find the f(c) guaranteed by the Mean Value Theorem for Integration on the
function 
f(x)=ln(x)/x  on the interval [1, 100].

Comment: I suggest you write out what the Mean Value Theorem says. It will have an integral in it. I suggest you evaluate that integral. I bet if you do all that you will be able to find $f(c)$.

Comment: i tried the theorem: [f(b)- f(a)]/[b-a] ... that's as far as i understood @Nameless

Comment: @lias That's the Mean Value Theorem for derivatives not the Mean Value Theorem for Integration.

Comment: ahhh ok, thanku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has
$$\int_1^{100}{\log x\over x}\ dx={1\over2}\bigl(\log x\bigr)^2\Biggr|_1^{100}={1\over2}\bigl(\log 100\bigr)^2\ .$$
In order to "find the $f(c)$ whose existence is guaranteed by the mean value theorem" we therefore have to solve the equation
$$(100-1) f(c)={1\over2}\bigl(\log 100\bigr)^2$$
for $f(c)$. The result is
$$f(c)={1\over198}\bigl(\log 100\bigr)^2\doteq 0.107\ .$$
Actually we have not used the MVT at all. We just have computed the average value of $f$ on the interval $[1,100]$. The essence of the MVT is that MVT guarantees the existence of a $c\in[1,100]$ such that $f(c)$ is equal to this average. As $f(1)=0$ and $f(10)\doteq0.23$, by the intermediate value theorem there has to be such a $c\in[1,10]$, even.